# Entity objects to business object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I'm working on a new project and wanted to use MVC and entity framework. For the purpose of separation of concerns. I plan to structure my project like so..

- MyProject.Web (this project houses the V and C of MVC)
- MyProject.Model (this project houses the M of MVC so that it can be reused and shared. This is where my business objects/ domain objects live)
- MyProject.BLL (this is where I write my business logic and make available via an interface)
- MyProject.Entity (this is my DAL - where entity objects will be generated by the wizard using db first approach)

My question is what is the best way to convert entity object to business object in my BLL? My mapping requires that I join two tables and compute a sum that would map to a field in a business object.

Not sure this is a good example but let say I join customer table and order table and got two records back for the same customer. One is for order placed in the AM and one for order placed in the PM. I need to compute the total for the day and mapped it to a field in my business object.

Automapper comes to mind  instead of manually code DTO, but I am not sure if it can do complex mapping (with the sum calculation)?

Is there a way to manually configure custom map in EF 6 to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Automapper, you can use Projections for complex mappings or use AutoMapper's QueryableExtensions helper methods.

See Aggregations section in the following link.

> LINQ can support aggregate queries, and AutoMapper supports LINQ
>   extension methods

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

Comment: Thank you! Let me give it a try. I'll come back to post updates.

Comment: so I was looking at the automapper and a light bulb went up. Instead of using automapper. I simply created an extension for my entity object to return the sum of child records since all entity objects are partial classes. Not sure this is the right way to do it but it solves the problem. I'll mark your response as answer since it actually answers my question whether automapper can do aggregate. Thanks!

Comment: @NKD Its definitely a solid option. There are usually multiple ways to do things.